# HTTPserver python Hello world The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler 

class HelloHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
def do_GET(self):
    # First, send a 200 OK response.
    self.send_response(200)

    # Then send headers.
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8')
    self.end_headers()

    # Now, write the response body.
    self.wfile.write("Hello, World!\n".encode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
server_address = ('', 8000)  # Serve on all addresses, port 8000.
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, HelloHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The code above gives "The system cannot find the path specified." when I run it.
What does the error mean?

Comment: Can you also paste the command you used to run the code?

Comment: I ran it in vscode. If I run this code in spyder or any IDE, it works fine.

Comment: I guess it's some configuration issue with your vscode.

Comment: Alright ! I'll see if I can do something about this configuration. Thanks :)